# validate method returns fields, which are not required

Tags: c#, validation, tfs, tfs-workitem

When I'm creating a new workitem, I set it up like:

```
WorkItem workitem = new WorkiItem(workItemType);
```

And then I'm getting all required fields by simply validating directly, so I know which fields I need to fill before saving.

```
ArrayList requiredFields = workitem.Validate();
```

But inside of my requiredFields, there a fields, which aren't marked as a required fields in the fielddefinition. There is for example a field "Assigned To", which is not a required field, so I can create a workitem inside of the TFS-Webapplication without filling this field. So why it gets put into the requiredField list while validating? I don't want to save it, if it's not validated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get required fields for some WorkItem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21621866/get-required-fields-for-some-workitem)

Comment: What's the type of the validated workitem? Assigned To field is required for some work item types.

Answer (score 0):

WorkItem validation is defined in the WorkItemType's template. Fields can have different validation requirements based on the **WorkItem's current state**(option1) or **the current user's permissions**(option2) The following code is an example for this two options for your reference:

```
 // Set the following variables accordingly
        string workItemTypeName = "Bug";
        string teamProjectName = "My Project";
        string usernameToImpersonate = "XXX";
        string tfsTeamProjectCollectionUrl = "http://xxx:8080/tfs/defaultcollection";

    // OPTION 1: no impersonation.
    // Get an instance to TFS using the current thread's identity.
    // NOTE: The current thread's identity needs to have the "" permision or else you will receive
    //       a runtime SOAP exception: "Access Denied: [username] needs the following permission(s) to perform this action: Make requests on behalf of others"
    TfsTeamProjectCollection tfs = new TfsTeamProjectCollection( new Uri( tfsTeamProjectCollectionUrl ) );
    IIdentityManagementService identityManagementService = tfs.GetService<IIdentityManagementService>();

    // OPTION 2: impersonation.  Remove the following two lines of code if you don't need to impersonate.
    // Get an instance to TFS impersonating the specified user.
    // NOTE: This is not needed if the current thread's identity is that of the user 
    //       needed to impersonate. Simple use the ablve TfsTeamProjectCollection instance
    TeamFoundationIdentity identity = identityManagementService.ReadIdentity( IdentitySearchFactor.AccountName, usernameToImpersonate, MembershipQuery.None, ReadIdentityOptions.None );
    tfs = new TfsTeamProjectCollection( tfs.Uri, identity.Descriptor );

    WorkItem workItem = null;
    WorkItemStore store = tfs.GetService<WorkItemStore>();

    // Determine if we are creating a new WorkItem or loading an existing WorkItem.
    if( workItemId.HasValue ) {
       workItem = store.GetWorkItem( workItemId.Value );
    }
    else {
       Project project = store.Projects[ teamProjectName ];
       WorkItemType workItemType = project.WorkItemTypes[ workItemTypeName ];
       workItem = new WorkItem( workItemType );
    }

    if( workItem != null ) {

       foreach( Field field in workItem.Fields ) {
          if( field.IsRequired ) {
             // TODO
          }
       }
    }
```

Comment: that seems helpful, but where do you get the workItemId-variable?

Comment: Using workItemId as an example so that you can see how to get an existing workItem. If your application supports editing existing work items, when you will need to get the existing work item to see which fields are required. If you're only always creating new work items, then yes, you don't need the if (workItemId.HasValue)

Comment: More details please refer this tutorial https://blog.joergbattermann.com/2016/05/05/vsts-tfs-rest-api-06-retrieving-and-querying-for-existing-work-items/